# Keep scroll to top button in the same height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I've a problem with my button. What I want is when the windows size on the height is changed, how can force the button to stay in the same height? I don't want it to follow or be pressed down as the height is changed...

http://jsfiddle.net/ccq9cs9L/3/

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="scrollToTop hidden-phone">
    <span class="icon icon-arrow-up-white"></span>
</a>
<div class="myDiv">
    <div class="myContent">
        a lot of text
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
a.scrollToTop {
    content: "";
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 60px;
    height: 45px;
    background: #78b209;
    position: fixed;
    top: 35.5%;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).scroll(function(e) { // This is scrollToTop button
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn(); 
    } else {
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut(); 
    }
});
$('.scrollToTop').click(function () { // Scroll to top with ease
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000, 'easeOutExpo');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Right now button stays in the same place (due to `position: fixed;`). Isn't it the desired behaviour?

Comment: do you mean that when the page height is increased, the button moves higher up the page?? If so, that is because you have this: `a.scrollToTop {top: 35.5%;}`

Comment: Yes it is, but I want the scroll to stay at the same position as always even though I have a fixed position... Trying to figure out how to do so in some jQuery like resize on height... Can someone help me with this?

Comment: @wf4 Yes, I understand that, but is it possible to make the button be in the same position if the height decreases or increases? on resize?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your question is actually about CSS. Try changing `top: 35.5%;` to a static amount, for example `top: 100px;`

If you want the pixel amount to be based on the viewport height, you can get that with

```
$(window).height();
```

So to always show the button at position N % from the top and keep it there despite viewport resizing you could do this:

```
function positionButton() {
    var percFromTop = 35,
        newHeight = $(window).height() / 100 * percFromTop;
    $(".scrollToTop").css("top", newHeight+"px");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    positionButton();
};
```

See it in a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ccq9cs9L/9/

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a way to dynamically set the distance from the top so that it has the impression of being fixed. This answer would make the button move up if the window is resized.

Comment: @wf4 OP words are _stay at the same position as always_, _stay in the same height_. So it looks like correct answer, doesn't it?

Comment: @wf4 Exactly, I want the button to me dynamic, yes! Adding pixels instead of percent doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @wf4 I didn't test it, because it felt like a trivial function, but apparently I should have. There were a few typos, and one brain hiccupt: As far as I understand the button shouldn't be repositioned on resize, because then the functionality is exactly the same as with pure CSS. Just positioning it once at load should give the desired functionality, assuming that I understood the requirements correctly.

Comment: @rsvmrk Fiddle added!